# Remove extra lines from file using hive script

Tags: hive, hiveql

i have some text files, some among them has header, some dont and some have extra lines before the actual record starts. Is there a way to remove the extra lines. Basically I am creating a external table using the file in the specified location. Any links will be really helpful.

Basically , there is no specific number of lines over which the headers are spanned, else i could have skipped the headers using

tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")

Answer (score 0):

Only filtering will help in this case. Filter your headers during select from table:

```
select t.* 
  from your_table t
 where t.col not in ('header_value1','header_value2','header_value3')
```

this will filter out NULLs also. To allow NULLs add `OR t.col is NULL`